# Поднятие старых вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки

Начинает раздражать уже, что мои прошлогодние вопросы при каждой НЕ моей правки, поднимаются.

Мне например не хочется чтобы какой-то мой старый вопрос обсуждали, минусовали и т.д., тем более, если в нём уже есть ответ, зачем ещё ответы там?

Comment: @NickVolynkin извиняюсь, хотел лишь дополнить вопрос контекстом, т.к. автор не упомянул причины своего недовольства, а это важно для понимания проблемы.

Comment: @KromStern: мне кажется, понять можно и так, а участники с детективными способностями могут пойти в мою историю правок и узнать всю правду)

Comment: Сейчас [эффект Стрейзанд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4) будет, и о вашем прошлогоднем вопросе ещё больше людей узнает :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**В общем и целом, обращаясь к сообществу:**

Технологии постоянно меняются, появляются более эффективные способы решать задачи. На старые вопросы можно и нужно давать ответы, предлагающие новые решения (либо править существующие ответы).

Все вопросы и ответы публикуются под CC-BY-SA и своим авторам практически не принадлежат (не знаю юридических тонкостей). Смысл хранить их на сайте — в том, чтобы они были полезны другим пользователям. Иначе можно было бы их удалять сразу, как получен ответ. По этой же причине вопросы поднимаются после правки: это привлекает к ним внимание.

Обычно мы задаем актуальные для нас на данный момент вопросы. Через несколько лет, с высоты нового профессионального уровня эти вопросы могут казаться слишком простыми или неуместными. Ничего плохого в этом нет. В каждый момент времени есть тысячи новичков, которые находятся на том же уровне, на котором были мы N лет назад. Они задают точно такие же вопросы и нуждаются в ответах на них.

Лучшее, что можно делать с такими вопросами, на мой взгляд — привести их в порядок. Поправить формулировки, метки, ссылки. Возможно, дать новый, более полный ответ.

Если вы совершенно точно не хотите привлекать внимание к себе в связи с каким-то новичковым вопросом, то можно попросить модератора открепить вопрос от учетной записи. Насколько я знаю, это вполне реально.

**В данной конкретной ситуации, обращаясь к автору вопроса:** я отредактировал ваш ответ на ваш же вопрос, чтобы его (ответ) не удаляли. По себе знаю, что бывает неприятно, когда удаляют сообщения, особенно если без предупреждения. Поэтому стараюсь по возможности не удалять, а править. Сожалею, что это привлекло лишнее внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 9):

IT - быстро развивающаяся отрасль. Ответы, которые верны сегодня, через год могут оказаться либо ошибочными, либо неоптимальными. Если вопрос кто-то отредактировал, значит он все еще для кого-то  актуален. На мой взгляд, в качественных ответах на старые вопросы нет ничего плохого.